# How to insert html element inside another element which already have some html?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an html structure like this.

```
<ul class="foo">
    <li class="bar">
        <a href="bar.html">Bar Html</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to rewrite the html using jquery as

```
<ul class="foo">
     <li class="bar">
          <span class="spanclass">
               <a href="bar.html">Bar Html</a>
          </span>
     </li>
</ul>
```

So my question is how can I achieve this using jquery, I simply need to insert an  html element inside an html element so that the content of the html still be there inside the newly inserted html.

If I Rephrase the code like this

```
<ul class="foo">
     <li class="bar">
        <a href="bar.html">Bar Html</a>
        <ul class="sub foo">
            <li class="sub bar">
                <a href="sub-bar.html">Sub Bar Html</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I want to get the result like my previous question, then how should I proceed. The Result should be as below.

```
<ul class="foo">
     <li class="bar">
        <div class="divclass">
            <a href="bar.html">Bar Html</a>
            <ul class="sub foo">
                <li class="sub bar">
                    <a href="sub-bar.html">Sub Bar Html</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try to read this: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: You would say that you want to "wrap" the inner HTML. (I sympathize; before you Google something you almost always have to know half the answer already).

Comment: Yes Wrap would have been the correct term, but I need something else, can you please check once again my rephrased code.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('ul.foo li.bar a').wrap('<span class="spanclass">')
```

Will produce:

```
<ul class="foo">
    <li class="bar">
        <span class="spanclass"><a href="bar.html">Bar Html</a></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Fjd25/)**

See: [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

Comment: Beat me to the punch! +1 for you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

WrapInner method is the answer for my question.

```
$('ul.foo li.bar').wrapInner('<div class="divclass">')
```

Will product the below code.

```
<ul class="foo">
 <li class="bar">
    <div class="divclass">
        <a href="bar.html">Bar Html</a>
        <ul class="sub foo">
            <li class="sub bar">
                <a href="sub-bar.html">Sub Bar Html</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```